# How detect when received a notification

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-cordova, onesignal

I need know the function to detect the notifications. I can send and receive notifications, but i need a function to detect when receive the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notificationOpenedCallback` will fire when a notification is either opened or if one is received while the app is in focus. Example below.

```
var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
  console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
};

window.plugins.OneSignal.init("b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba",
                             {googleProjectNumber: "703322744261"},
                             notificationOpenedCallback);
```

There isn't an event for when a notification is receive in the background through Corodva. You will need to use native code for this by setting up a `NotificationExtenderService` in Java by following the OneSignal [Background Data and Notification Overriding](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-customizations#background-data-and-notification-overriding) documentation for Android. For iOS set `content_available` to true and setup a
[- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) selector.